# Which style of stored procedure writing is better?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to write 5 `SELECT` statements of different types, but with the same purpose.

Should I write 5 individual stored procedure for them?

OR should I write one stored procedure and follow the `CASE` style to go to the specific stored procedure?

The 5 simple `SELECT` statements are like :

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM table1 WHERE vv = 'ss'
SELECT a, b, c FROM table2 WHERE vv = 'ss'
```

Comment: Can you explain what these 5 different `SELECT` statements are supposed to do? There's not a lot of info to go by with what you listed so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise there is advantage of having different SPs, as it can have different execution plans and SQL server can pick up the correct execution plan, more efficiently.

Having one procedure is more maintainable  and will reduce code..

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a stored procedure with a dynamic query, where your parameter points to the correct table.

```
Create proc test (@table varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @str varchar (MAX)
SET @str = 'SELECT a, b, c FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE vv = ''ss'''
EXEC(@str)
```

Pro's here: your tablename is dynamic
con's: U need to define this tablename where you call the procedure.

Comment: May be I was not clear..but if tables are different means the table structure would be different too..